# Sites hosted in subdirectory resolve to incorrect URL

Tags: https, plesk

We have three web sites hosted under one account and recently upgraded all three sites to HTTPS. The hosting account is Plesk. The primary site is fine but the two other sites, which reside in a subdirectory under the main one, exhibit a strange new problem. If you type in the domain the site comes up fine https://www.example.com/ but if you click on a link to the domain (from an email, from  a google search, from a web link), the URL that comes up is https://www.example.com/example.com/. Godaddy has said that it's a problem with the web.config file but they won't suggest a solution. There is a web.config file in the primary root but not in the subdomain root folders, as that is what they said to do when the HTTPS was set up. The web.config file in the root directory contains the following code:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true"> 
    <match url="(.*)" /> 
    <conditions> 
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions> 
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>   
    </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Anyone out there able to help?

Comment: Seems like more of a "Server Fault" question.